# How to deselect list items in react admin custom bulk action buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I have a react admin project and have implemented a custom button for the List view passed into the `bulkActionButtons` attribute as described by the docs here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#bulk-action-buttons

```
const BulkUserActions = props => (
  <MakeAdminButton {...props}/>
);

const UserList = props => (
  <List {...props} bulkActionButtons={<BulkUserActions/>}>
    <Datagrid rowClick="show">
      <TextField source="id"/>
      <EmailField source="email"/>
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

The `MakeAdminButton` handles the click and performs the update that I need. The missing piece of the puzzle is how to deselect the list items after the action is completed. The `props.selectedIds` is protected so I am unable to simply set this to an empty array after completing my logic.

Question is how to unset `props.selectedIds` or other method for deselecting the list items on completion.

```
const MakeAdminButton = withStyles(styles)(class MakeAdminButton extends React.Component {

  handleAction = () => {
    //does the stuff as required using this.props.selectedIds

    //what to return to unset this.props.selectedIds 
  };

  render () {
    return <Button variant="contained"
               color="primary"
               onClick={this.handleAction}
    <AdminIcon/>
  </Button>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

React Admin provide ways of doing it. On v3 directly with useUnselectAll or on onSuccess callback of useMutation, useUpdateMany and useDataProvider hooks. On v2 with dataProvider fourth argument of withDataProvider decorator or seting meta.onSuccess.unselectAll to true of custom redux actions, or automatically with crudUpdateMany, or options prop of Mutation component.

For v2 with crudUpdateMany, `goto` Mike Miller answer.

Working examples:

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-firefly-dd1ni?file=/src/App.js

v3:

```
const UnselectAllButtonV3Hook = props => {
  const unselectAll = useUnselectAll();

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        unselectAll(props.resource);
      }}
    >
      Unselect all with v3 hook
    </Button>
  );
};
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Actions.html#handling-side-effects-in-usedataprovider

useUpdateMany/useDataProvider/useMutation hooks, onSuccess callback calling `unselectAll()` from `useUnselectAll()`

```
const MakeAdminButtonV3 = props => {
  const refresh = useRefresh();
  const unselectAll = useUnselectAll();

  const [makeAdmin, { loading }] = useUpdateMany(
    props.resource,
    props.selectedIds,
    { isAdmin: true },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        unselectAll(props.resource);
        refresh();
      }
    }
  );

  //OR

  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();

  const makeAdmin2 = () => {
    dataProvider.updateMany(
      props.resource,
      { ids: props.selectedIds, data: { isAdmin: true } },
      {
        onSuccess: () => {
          unselectAll(props.resource);
          refresh();
        }
      }
    );
  };

  //OR

  const [makeAdmin3, { loading3 }] = useMutation(
    {
      type: "updateMany",
      resource: props.resource,
      payload: { ids: props.selectedIds, data: { isAdmin: true } }
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        unselectAll(props.resource);
        refresh();
      }
    }
  );

  return (
    <Button onClick={makeAdmin3} disabled={loading3}>
      Make Admin with V3 dataProvider hooks
    </Button>
  );
};
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Actions.html#usemutation-hook

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Actions.html#usedataprovider-hook

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Actions.html#specialized-hooks

V2 examples also work on v3, but Mutation and withDataProvider is legacy, with a small change while using dataProvider directly, since dataProvider api on v3 changed.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Actions.html#legacy-components-query-mutation-and-withdataprovider

v2:

withDataProvider:

```
const UnmakeAdminButtonWithWithDataProvider = withDataProvider(
  class extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
      this.props.dataProvider(
        UPDATE_MANY,
        "users",
        { ids: this.props.selectedIds, data: { isAdmin: false } },
        { onSuccess: { unselectAll: true, refresh: true } }
      );
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Unmake Admin with withDataProvider
        </Button>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html#handling-side-effects

custom redux action:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const MAKE_ADMIN = "MAKE_ADMIN";

const makeAdmin = ids => ({
  type: MAKE_ADMIN,
  payload: { ids, data: { isAdmin: true } },
  meta: {
    fetch: UPDATE_MANY,
    resource: "users",
    onSuccess: { unselectAll: true, refresh: true }
  }
});

const MakeAdminButtonWithCustomAction = connect(
  null,
  { makeAdmin }
)(
  class extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
      this.props.makeAdmin(this.props.selectedIds);
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Make Admin With Custom Redux Action
        </Button>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html#adding-side-effects-to-actions

Mutation component:

```
const MakeAdminMutationV2 = props => (
  <Mutation
    type="updateMany" //{UPDATE_MANY}
    resource={props.resource}
    payload={{ ids: props.selectedIds, data: { isAdmin: true } }}
    options={{
      onSuccess: {
        unselectAll: true,
        refresh: true
      }
    }}
  >
    {approve => <Button onClick={approve}>Make admin with Mutation</Button>}
  </Mutation>
);
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html#query-and-mutation-components

Answer (score 0):

Set up some meta data for each time you click the checkbox, so it injects true or false into the array like:

```
listData = {
   ...
   isChecked : true
}
```

Then inside the function that handles the bulk operations, add a `[listData].filter( )`, (lodash filter is faster), to check and see which `isChecked === true`, and then set them to false, and update the `value={bool}` attribute on the checkbox input tag.

Comment: Thanks Joe but in react admin I am not responsible for setting the checked array this is handled by this component https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#the-list-component. The custom action receives an array of selectedIds but does not have access to unset them

Comment: Nope I am looking into the API for the react-admin List.bulkActionButtons. I figured it out, requires calling a helper function `crudUpdateMany` to perform an update. This triggers the change to the redux store and unsets the prop

Comment: Sorry, wish I could've helped....  I gave it the ole' college try at least.

Comment: Appreciate the help - more than I got from the react-admin guys

Comment: Glad you figured it out, take care and I'll keep a look out for you on here.

Comment: Did anyone managed to unset the property without calling crudUpdateMany?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to call a bulk helper function from react admin:

```
class MakeAdminButton extends React.Component {

handleAction = () => {
 const { basePath, crudUpdateMany, resource, selectedIds } = this.props;

 //custom code goes in here...

 //calling this function triggers the unset and closes the toolbar
 crudUpdateMany(resource, selectedIds, { isAdmin: true }, basePath);
 };

render () {
  return <Button label="Make Admin" onClick={this.handleAction}>
    <AdminIcon/>
  </Button>;
 }
};

const BulkUserActions = connect(undefined, { crudUpdateMany })(MakeAdminButton);

const UserList = props => (
 <List {...props} bulkActionButtons={<BulkUserActions/>}>
  <Datagrid>
   <TextField source="id"/>
   <EmailField source="email"/>
   <BooleanField source="isAdmin" label="Admin" />
 </Datagrid>
</List>
);
```

An example is shown on this page if I had bothered to read it properly:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/List.md#bulk-action-buttons